# exchanging values in a select list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html-select, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to swap select option values with jQuery when a links clicked, at the moment its just resetting the select when the links clicked, not sure what's going wrong?:

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("#swapCurrency").click(function (e) {
        var selectOne = $("#currency-from").html();
        var selectTwo = $("#currency-to").html();
        $("#currency-from").html(selectTwo);
        $("#currency-to").html(selectOne);
        return false;
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tchh2/

Comment: You are swapping the entire inner HTML content, when you want to swap only the values.

Comment: You need to explain what you want to do.  Do you want to swap the option elements from each select, or just swap values?  Why do all the options in one of the selects have the same value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote it in a step-by-step way so it is easier to understand:

```
$("#swapCurrency").click(function (e) {

    //get the DOM elements for the selects, store them into variables
    var selectOne = $("#currency-from");
    var selectTwo = $("#currency-to");

    //get all the direct children of the selects (option or optgroup elements)
    //and remove them from the DOM but keep events and data (detach)
    //and store them into variables
    //after this, both selects will be empty
    var childrenOne = selectOne.children().detach();
    var childrenTwo = selectTwo.children().detach();

    //put the children into their new home
    childrenOne.appendTo(selectTwo);
    childrenTwo.appendTo(selectOne);

    return false;
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/tchh2/4/)

Your approach works with transforming DOM elements to HTML and back. The problem is you lose important information this way, like which element was `selected` (it is stored in a DOM property, not an HTML attribute, it just gives the starting point).

- [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)
- [detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)
- [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Answer (score 2):

That happens because you remove all elements from both `<select>` fields and put them as new again. To make it working as expected you'd better move the *actual* elements as follows:

```
$("#swapCurrency").click(function(e) {
    var options = $("#currency-from > option").detach();
    $("#currency-to > option").appendTo("#currency-from");
    $("#currency-to").append(options);
    return false;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tchh2/2/

Comment: +1 would be nice if you add explanation for `detach()`

Comment: Not required in the current example, but `optgroup`s can also be found in a `select`.

Comment: @kapa Then the selector should be slightly amended, as if the IDs of elements are changed.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the whole HTML (every option) within the `<select>`. As long as each select has the same amount of options and they correspond to each other, you can use the selected index property to swap them:

```
$("#swapCurrency").click(function (e) {
    var selOne = document.getElementById('currency-from'),
        selTwo = document.getElementById('currency-to');
    var selectOne = selOne.selectedIndex;
    var selectTwo = selTwo.selectedIndex;
    selOne.selectedIndex = selectTwo;
    selTwo.selectedIndex = selectOne;
    return false;
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/tchh2/7/)

Comment: Amount of options is the same but the actual values and set of attributes are different. Check out the JSFiddle supplied by the OP.

Comment: @VisioN Fair point. But it could be possible that the OP doesn't want to move the element itself, they just want to change each select to the option that corresponds to the other. I don't think it deserved a down-vote.

Comment: I agree with you with this point but I haven't downvoted you.